# How do I get Knockout to bind the value of a select box to a property of a list item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

How do I get Knockout to bind the value of a select box to a property of a list item?

I have a ASP.NET MVC strongly typed view to IEnermerable of MyViewModel and MyViewModel is defined as

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Status{get;set;}
}
```

I'm using, trying to use, knockout to data bind the collection of MyViewModel such that the user can change the Status using a drop down. My view js looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

var statusItems = [
        { id: 0, name: 'New' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Improved' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Bad' }
];

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Items = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

    self.statuses = statusItems;

    self.remove = function () {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the entry?\nThis operation cannot be undone.')) {
            self.Items.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And my markup is

```
<div id="dashboard-div">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { id = "dashboardForm" }))
    {
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: Name" /><input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id, attr: { name: '['+$index()+'].Id'}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="status-dropdown" data-bind="options: $parent.statuses, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: Status" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <button data-bind="enable: Items().length > 0" type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is the drop down value is not being bound to Status. on initial page load the drop down value is properly set. i.e. if it's 1 in the database the  will have 'Improved' selected but when I get to the Save method in my controller the Status for each Item (MyViewModel) is 0. if i change the Status property to type string everything again works until you get to the controller where all the values of Status are null.

Comment: *sigh* i knew as soon as i asked i would figure out my issue. i needed to add the attribute name to the select so that model binding would work.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Can you add it as an answer and accept it? That way your question won't show up in the list of unanswered Knockout questions.

Answer (score 0):

Brent said:

I knew as soon as i asked i would figure out my issue. i needed to add the attribute name to the select so that model binding would work.

Just adding this here so others find his solution quicker...